# Outlook restore file extension?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, session, recovery

Outlook saves recover information in a file that is used after an unintentional shutdawn with the /restore switch.  Does anybody remember the extension for the recovery file?

Comment: [not an outlook user] Do you mean a .pst file?

Comment: @Gantendo the .pst file is where Outlook stores defined offline mail. Locally cached content is stored in an .ost file.

Comment: What sort of things are you assuming are stored in this theoretical file? Outlook's offline cache file is an .ost file, but I don't know if this is what Outlook polls for crash recovery information. Please clarify your question, explain what you have actually searched for (we know you haven't actually searched "everything" or "everywhere" and so it's not helpful to us or to yourself to tell us you have), explain what you're trying to accomplish and why. This information can help us better understand what you are asking and so get you a good answer.

Comment: You can look at whats in there with https://www.kerneldatarecovery.com/ost-viewer.html

Comment: Outlook can be opened using the /restore switch to re-open in the state it was in prior to the last inadvertant shutdown.

Here's my recover startup link:  
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /restore
There is a file that Outlook saves which contains information to allow it to restore to the last state prior to a crash - which emails and drafts were open.

Comment: Ugh...

Outlook can be opened using the /restore switch to re-open in the state it was in prior to the last inadvertant shutdown.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /restore

It saves the state information in a file which is used exclusively for this purpose.  I have searched everything I can think of having to do with restore, recover, etc.

If the restore doesn't work for any reason, (in this case, an upgrade failure) the previous file gets overwritten when you shut down Outlook again, so it's necessary to copy it while it still contains the recover info.

Comment: 10 years ago this was easy to find, but there are now so many virtually duplicate articles on Outlook - Restore that the needle is now hidden in acres of hay...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your requirement. Therefore, I'm here to confirm: Do you want to find a file(**OUTLOOK.EXE**) used to recover an unintentional Outlook shutdawn and this file's location? If so, the following location may be the thing you want: ***C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE***

Comment: Hi, It's been a while, is there update?